# javascript - pick unique items from first array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash, uniq

Suppose I have two arrays of objects

```
const array1 =  [{
        listName: 'My top 5 Sci-Fi Movies',
        listCreator: 'Anon',
        listItem: 'The Fifth Element'
      },
      {
        listName: 'My top 5 Sci-Fi Movies',
        listCreator: 'Anon',
        listItem: 'Cube'
      }]
```

and

```
const array2 = [{
        listName: 'My top 5 Sci-Fi Movies',
        listCreator: 'Anon',
        listItem: 'The Fifth Element'
      },
      {
        listName: 'My top 5 Sci-Fi Movies',
        listCreator: 'Dude',
        listItem: 'Cube'
      }]
```

I want to able to compare the two arrays and create a new array that only has unique members of `array1`, in this case

```
const uniqueArray = [{
            listName: 'My top 5 Sci-Fi Movies',
            listCreator: 'Anon',
            listItem: 'Cube'
          }]
```

I am using lodash library (but not necessary to solve this problem if not required) and I'd like to accomplish this in the fewest lines of code possible.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your inputs and expected output. Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: I had tried _.uniq, _.uniWith (used with _.isEqual) Set. I'm sorry I don't have details. I just learning JS and had been at this for a couple of days trying different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After banging my head around the intertubes, I found a simple and elegant solution.

If I (using lodash) do

```
const arrNew = _.differenceWith(array1, array2, _.isEqual);
```

arrNew is a new array of unique items from array1. Hope this helps someone else out.
Would love to see if there's another more performant solution.

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#differenceWith

Answer (score 1):

hello dear brother you use Hashset to fetch automatically Unique Data from list

```
HashSet<Integer>set = new HashSet<Integer>(list1);
List<Integer>list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(set);
```

and then pass this Hashset to List again

ITS JAVA CODE BUT LOGIC IS SAME FOR EVERY LANGUAGE